# Image draw pixel by pixel from double array

Tags: c#, wpf, image, pixel

I am trying to achieve something but after hours of search, I decided just to ask the more experienced. I am reading a pgm file(grayscale image represented with the value of gray for every pixel) and loading it into double array => data[,]. I am trying to make a double loop that will fill an image object in WPF window with the correct grayscale value for every pixel.

Here is my need more code-like represented:

```
int[,] data = new int[img.width,img.height];` 
for(int i=0; i<img.Height;i++)`
{
    for(int j=0; j<img.Width;j++)
    {
        //line that will fill image with pixel[i,j];
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not simply display the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the example provided by microsoft on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It's an assignment for school so I have no choice but to do it with Bitmap.SetPixels

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for [Bitmap.SetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. However, this may prove to be quite slow processing. You can speed up performance by using [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.